# Basic PHP if logic for multiple statements

Tags: php, logic

I want to include `addtohomescreen.php` in a page only for the following conditions:

1. `$ua !== 'sattamatka.pro'` -> True
2. `$ua !== 'sattamatka.android'` -> True
3. `stripos($ua,'android') == true)` -> True

**Note:** **For condition `1` & `2` if either one is true the other becomes false automatically.**

I am using the following logic:

```
<?php
if($ua !== 'sattamatka.pro' 
|| $ua !== 'sattamatka.android' 
&& stripos($ua,'android') == true) {
include "addtohomescreen.php";
}
?>
```

**Note:** I want all of them true. But if I use `&&` in place of `||` both of the statements - `$ua !== 'sattamatka.pro'` and `$ua !== 'sattamatka.android'` becomes false and `addtohomescreen.php` is included in both the `$ua`.

**Edit**: The possible vales of `$ua` are:

1. `sattamatka.pro`
2. `sattamatka.android`
3. `mozilla/5.0 (linux; u; android 6.0.1; en-us; redmi note 3 build/mmb29m) applewebkit/534.30 (khtml, like gecko) version/4.0 ucbrowser/11.2.5.932 u3/0.8.0 mobile safari/534.30`

**Update**: Problem was for `$ua = 'sattamatka.pro'` and `$ua = 'sattamatka.android'` the statement `if(($ua !== 'sattamatka.pro') && ($ua !== 'sattamatka.android') && (stripos($ua,'android') == true))` returned false. This has been solved by adding `()` to `($ua !== 'sattamatka.pro') || ($ua !== 'sattamatka.android')` & now the code works as expected. I don't need any more suggestions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: Replace `||` with `&&`

Comment: So you want something to be done if condition 1 is true ***and*** condition 2 is true ***and*** condition 3 is true? Then why are you using the *or* operator `||`?

Comment: That's the problem. I want all of them true. But if I use && in place of || for either of the $ua the statement becomes false.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If you use `&&` instead, do you mean that the expression sis true for some value it *shouldn't* be true on? What is the value of `$ua` that causes the false positive?

Comment: @MaroofMandal check the edited answer

Comment: @MuhammadAsif And how is that different than that I have mentioned above?

Comment: will you provide value for `$ua` so that confusion can be overcome

Comment: @MaroofMandal according to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php && operator's precedence is higher than ||. So in your situation, the AND condition is being evaluated first and if it comes true, the OR condition would't matter. That's the problem you're facing. So to overcome it, surround the OR with brackets to to check OR before AND

Comment: @B.Desai  added the values for $ua

Comment: ok and from these 3 of them for which you have to include "addtohomescreen.php"?

Comment: It seems like you basically want to include it if the `$ua` contains `android` and isn't `sattamatka.android`? Then why not do: `if (stripos($ua,'android') !== false && $ua !== 'sattamatka.android')` ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you don't get the problem here. I found a solution and I have added the answer below.

Comment: @MaroofMandal Read the updated question: _"The possible vales of $ua are:"_ and then three possible values. Maybe you need to actually ask the question properly? According to what you've asked, you have gotten multiple comments that _would_ solve that issue. If it still doesn't work, then _it's your question_ that's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding `()` to the first two statements:

```
    <?php
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if(($ua !== 'sattamatka.pro' 
    || $ua !== 'sattamatka.android') 
    && stripos($ua,'android') == true) {
    include "addtohomescreen.php";
    }
    else {}
    ?>
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: You do realize that the above statement is exactly the same as: `if (stripos($ua,'android') == true)`? The first group will _always_ return true, since `$ua` will _always_ be not equal to at least one of the two checks.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You don't get it. Let me explain it to you in simpler language. I do not want to include `addtohomescreen.php` if the $ua is either `sattamatka.pro` or `sattamatka.android` but I want to include it if the `$ua` contains the word `android` so both of the first two statements must always be true and if not the one of them becomes false.

Comment: And you're not listening. The first check `($ua !== 'sattamatka.pro' || $ua !== 'sattamatka.android')` is _useless_ since that block will _always_ return true. No matter what `$ua` contains, it will be _not equal_ to at least _one_ of them in will therefor _always_ return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` if you want all condition to become `true`

```
if(($ua !== 'sattamatka.pro') && ($ua !== 'sattamatka.android') && (stripos($ua,'android') == true)) {
include "addtohomescreen.php";
}
```

Comment: How is it different than what's already commented above? For small typos or corrections, lets not add answers, if can be attainable by adding a comment.

Comment: I want all of them true. But if I use `&&` in place of `||` both of the statements - `$ua !== 'sattamatka.pro'` and `$ua !== 'sattamatka.android'` becomes false and `addtohomescreen.php` is included in both the `$ua`